# FFmpeg script does not loop

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have multiple video and sub files inside a directory.
My aim is to embed subtitles into each video.
My instance in directory:

```
   A.mp4
   A.ass
   B.mp4
   B.ass
   C.mp4
   C.ass
   .
   .
   Z.mp4
   Z.ass
```

My script:

```
   for f in *.mp4; do base=$(basename ${$f%.mp4}) ffmpeg -i $base.mp4 \
   -vf "ass=$base.ass" 222$base.mp4; done;
```

It works only for the first file, when the process finishes, it asks me to overwrite output file. Could you please explain why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

`base` is being interpreted as `$(basename ${$f%.mp4}) ffmpeg -i $base.mp4` (at least), and not just `$(basename ${$f%.mp4})`.

## Lazy solution

Add a semicolon:

```
for f in *.mp4; do base=$(basename "$f" .mp4); ffmpeg -i "$base.mp4" -vf "ass=$base.ass" "222$base.mp4"; done
```

Alternatively, break the command into multiple lines to separate `base` from the command. I also made some additional minor changes not related to the main issue (proper quoting, corrected `baseline` usage, stream copy audio instead of re-encode).

Check your original command/script with [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) for a more in-depth explanation and solutions.

## Better solution

Eliminate the extraneous `basename` process and use [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) instead:

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf "ass=${f%.*}.ass" -c:a copy "222${f%.*}.mp4"; done
```

This is more efficient and shorter.